# ptr records for mulitple vhosts (www and mail)

Tags: ptr-record

My IP address is shared between my webserver and mail server:

```
www.example.com A 123.123.123.123
mail.example.com A 123.123.123.123
```

Setting up a PTR record for mail affected both of my mail and web servers.

I do NOT want my webservers to respond to PTR lookup.  What are my options (other then adding additional IPs)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver does not respond to a PTR lookup, your DNS server does.

A ptr lookup is just a "question" for the DNS server, where you have (and send him) the IP, and want the domain name for that IP. There is no way to distingusih weather it's for a web service or a mail service.

Your only choice here is to use another different IPs.